# How to to extrapolate the column values with respect to its counter column values count to a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having the Source data frame like below ;

Source Dataframe

[image]

I would like to create a resultant data frame as follows ;

Resultant Dataframe

[image: Result dataframe]

Comment: Why `Orange` is not 1,2?

Comment: @ThePyGuy , sorry inadvertent error. Edited.

Comment: Hello @DhineshSanthalingam you have to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Parameter` as index, then call `.apply` on value and create `range` from *1 to n+1*, then `explode` and finally reset the index

```py
df.set_index('Parameter')['value'].apply(lambda x: range(1, x+1)).explode().reset_index()

  Parameter value
0     Apple     1
1    Orange     1
2    Orange     2
3     Mango     1
4     Mango     2
5     Mango     3
6     Mango     4
7     Mango     5
```

You can even avoid setting/resetting index,  by assigning column then exploding it:

```py
>>> df.assign(value=df['value'].apply(lambda x: range(1, x+1))).explode('value')
  Parameter value
0     Apple     1
1    Orange     1
1    Orange     2
2     Mango     1
2     Mango     2
2     Mango     3
2     Mango     4
2     Mango     5
```

Comment: @DhineshSanthalingam, Thats great! No need to thank

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
new_params = []
new_values = []

for param, value in zip(source_df.parameter, source_df.value):
    new_params.append([param]*value)
    new_values.append(list(range(1,value+1)))

resultant_df = pd.DataFrame({'parameter':new_params, 'value':new_values})
```

I cannot think of a simpler way using pandas.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Is there any more pythonic pandas way to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes, the proposed solution by @ThePyGuy is better :).